# How can I give my App one interface for iPhone and another for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

So here is my problem....

I did develop an app for the iPhone. I'm done so far and everything works fine.

But I don't won't iPad users to get annoyed because of bad graphics on their screen.

Anyway iPad is not just a big iPhone, I also would like to give iPad users a special iPad-interface.

Do I have to distribute two different apps to solve this issue?

And if I have to, how can I tell itunesconnect that one app is just for iPhone/iPod and the other one just for iPad?

Can anybody please tell me which way I have to go?

I would be very thankful for some help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Look at Universal Application - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+universal+app

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Answer (score 0):

You can build a universal app what will be valid for both iPhone and iPad devices. In this way you just distribute a single app. Itunes connect and the app store will be aware that your app is valid for both devices.

You can find info on how to create a universal app from an iPhone app here for example: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html